# Button won’t stay in line with list bullet

Tags: css

Okay, I start anew.

I need help getting the button and the pseudo-bullet in one line even if the button text has more than one line of text.

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <button>What happens when the button get very long? Will it still work out or will something bad happen? Hmm...</button>
        <p>Answer!</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item;
}

ol li {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: darkcyan;
    display: block;
}

ol li::before {
    content: counter(item) " ";
    counter-increment: item;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}

ol button {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #EEE;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/018rzjht/

Comment: Please read [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should isolate the custom **::before** list counter from the content. Create a wrapper around the content. Then using some simple Flexbox, you can control the list counter from the content itself. You also had some counting issues with your list items. By targeting just the direct descendent of the parent only, the count stays in track.

```css
.ordered-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
  display: inline;
  color: #C5BF9E;
}

.ordered-list > li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.ordered-list > li::before {
  content: counter(item) "";
  counter-increment: item;
  margin-right: 17px;
}

.ordered-list p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol class="ordered-list">
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      <button type="button" class="trigger-1"><span>Ihr woll<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">t</span>, dass ich <span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">f</span>ür Eu<span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">r</span>e schlec<span style="letter-spacing: 0.9px">h</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1px">t</span>en E<span style="letter-spacing: 0.9px">n</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">t</span>scheidungen b<span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">e</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">z</span>ahle? LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUM</span></button>

          <p>Wenn Ihr das so sag<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">t</span>, klin<span style="letter-spacing: 1px">g</span>t das i<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">r</span>gen<span style="letter-spacing: 1px">d</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">w</span>ie <span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">v</span>iel schlimmer. <br>Se<span style="letter-spacing: 0.9px">h</span>t es als Da<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">r</span>lehen a<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">n</span>. Ihr <span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">w</span>i<span style="letter-spacing: 0.9px">s</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">s</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">t</span>, dass ich es <span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">z</span>u<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">r</span>ü<span style="letter-spacing: 1px">c</span><span style="letter-spacing: 2.3px">k</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">z</span>ahlen kan<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">n</span>. Ich habe ein eh<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">r</span>liches Gesich<span style="letter-spacing: 2px">t</span>.</p>

          <ol>

           <li><p>In O<span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">r</span>dnu<span style="letter-spacing: 1px">n</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">g</span>. Hier ist e<span style="letter-spacing: 2px">t</span>was Gol<span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">d</span>, um Euch au<span style="letter-spacing: 1.4px">s</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">z</span>uhe<span style="letter-spacing: 0.9px">l</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.1px">f</span>e<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">n</span>.</p></li>

           <li><p>Nei<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">n</span>, <span style="letter-spacing: 1px">i</span>ch we<span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">r</span>de Euch kein Gold gebe<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">n</span>.</p></li>

           <li><p><span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">L</span>e<span style="letter-spacing: 1px">b</span>t <span style="letter-spacing: 1px">w</span>o<span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">h</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">l</span>.</p></li>

          </ol>

    </div></li>

         <li>

          <p><span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">L</span>e<span style="letter-spacing: 1px">b</span>t                 <span style="letter-spacing: 1px">w</span>o<span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">h</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">l</span>.</p>

  </li>
</ol>
```

https://codepen.io/shashi_lo/pen/WJYxom

Comment: I tried it with flexbox but the same problem would appear here.

Either I get this: https://jsfiddle.net/h7yex55e/. Or I get this: https://jsfiddle.net/mdgfoyh9/.

This is the only way I got it working with flexbox but it is also no good solution: https://jsfiddle.net/1gg40zqy/.

Comment: Based off your updated jsfiddle, If you contain the elements in <div>, and set the LI to display: flex;, everything works like how you wanted it.

https://jsfiddle.net/018rzjht/1/

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you so much, Shashi Lo!

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict the width of the button:

```
.dialogue-container ol button{
width: calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

Where the 15px is how much space you want to leave for the numbers.

If you want the postition of the button unchanged when you click you should define the before elements width too. Alsofor that to take effect you should add display block to id, and make it float right:

```
.dialogue-container ol li::before {
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great idea but the button toggles the content beneath it and every time I click on it it moves a little. Same goes for the solution with percentage. It’s much worse there.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found a solution and I thought I should share it here.

It’s based on the suggestion from Shashi Lo to use flexbox but I needed to build it differently so it wouldn’t cause any unwanted side effects.

Here is the result:

https://jsfiddle.net/cdjc6fk5/

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <button type="button">Ihr woll<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">t</span>, dass ich <span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">f</span>ür Eu<span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">r</span>e schlec<span style="letter-spacing: 0.9px">h</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1px">t</span>en E<span style="letter-spacing: 0.9px">n</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">t</span>scheidungen b<span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">e</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">z</span>ahle?</button>
    </li>

    <p>
        Wenn Ihr das so sag<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">t</span>, klin<span style="letter-spacing: 1px">g</span>t das i<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">r</span>gen<span style="letter-spacing: 1px">d</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">w</span>ie <span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">v</span>iel schlimmer. <br>Se<span style="letter-spacing: 0.9px">h</span>t es als Da<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">r</span>lehen a<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">n</span>. Ihr <span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">w</span>i<span style="letter-spacing: 0.9px">s</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.3px">s</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">t</span>, dass ich es <span style="letter-spacing: 1.2px">z</span>u<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">r</span>ü<span style="letter-spacing: 1px">c</span><span style="letter-spacing: 2.3px">k</span><span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">z</span>ahlen kan<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">n</span>. Ich habe ein eh<span style="letter-spacing: 1.5px">r</span>liches Gesich<span style="letter-spacing: 2px">t</span>.

    </p>

</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol {
margin: 4px 0 0 24px;
padding: 0;
background-color: limegreen;
list-style-type: none;
counter-reset: item;
}

ol li {
background-color: darkcyan;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

ol li::before {
width: 16px;
background-color: darkred;
counter-increment: item;
content: counter(item) "";
font-family: Segoe UI Semibold;
color: #C5BF9E;
}

button {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: black;
border: none;
outline: none;
vertical-align: top;
text-align: justify;
font-family: Segoe UI;
font-size: 1em;
color: #C5BF9E;
cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover { color: #EECA2A; }

ol p {
width: calc(100% - 16px);
margin: 0;
padding-left: 16px;
background-color: red;
font-family: Segoe UI;
font-size: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set width of button smaller than 100% and it will be in the same row, you don't need floating, just put `width: 95%;` or percentage you want